# What will be the Main of this program in java |How do i call the line method in main?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
package drawinglinebymethods;

import java.awt.*;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawingLineByMethods extends Frame {

    public JFrame f=new JFrame();

    void fra_size()
    {
        f.setSize(450, 300);
    }

    void fra_visible()
    {
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    void fra_title()
    {
        f.setTitle(" java frame");
    }

    void exit()
    {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void line(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(10, 10, 20, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingLineByMethods obj = new DrawingLineByMethods();
        obj.fra_size();
        obj.fra_title();
        obj.fra_visible();
        obj.fra_exit();
        obj.line(g);  // <-- error here
    }

}
```

Comment: `g` is simply undefined when you use it in `obj.line`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question suggests that you are not yet clear on how graphics and drawing works in Swing GUI's. Some suggestions for you:

- Don't have your class extend java.awt.Frame as this makes no sense. You're not creating an AWT Frame window and have no need of this.
- Create a class that extends JPanel and draw in its paintComponent method as the [Swing painting tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) (link now added) show you.
- You never call drawing code directly but rather it is indirectly called by the JVM.
- If you want to draw from outside of the GUI itself, then draw to a BufferedImage, one that is then displayed within the GUI.
- Don't use a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a GUI component as the object thus obtained will not persist, and this risks you creating unstable graphics or worse -- throwing a NullPointerException.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LineDraw extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 450;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;

    public LineDraw() {

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // use rendering hints to draw smooth lines
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // do drawing here
        g.drawLine(10, 10, 20, 300);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LineDraw mainPanel = new LineDraw();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Line Draw");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to add lines as the program runs, again, use a BufferedImage that is drawn within the JPanel's paintComponent method. When you need to add a new line to the GUI, extract the Graphics or Graphics2D object from the BufferedImage using `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()` respectively (it's OK to do this), draw with this Graphics object, *dispose of the Graphics object*, and repaint the GUI. For example in the code below, I draw a new line when the button is pressed by adding code within the JButton's ActionListener (actually its AbstractAction which is similar to an ActionListener but more powerful):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LineDraw extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 450;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private int yDistance = 20;
    private int deltaY = 10;

    public LineDraw() {
        img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        add(new JButton(new DrawLineAction("Draw Line", KeyEvent.VK_D)));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // draw the buffered image here
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }

        // use rendering hints to draw smooth lines
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // do drawing here
        g.drawLine(10, 10, 20, 300);
    }

    public void drawNewLines() {
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        yDistance += deltaY;
        g2.drawLine(10, 10, yDistance, PREF_H);

        g2.dispose();
        repaint();
    }

    private class DrawLineAction extends AbstractAction {
        public DrawLineAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name); // give button its text
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // alt-hot key for button
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawNewLines();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LineDraw mainPanel = new LineDraw();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Line Draw");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line is a non-static method, the only way to call it from a static method (main here) is to have an instance of the class.